# Android variables in strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, parsing, variables

Somewhere I read how to use variables in XML document. They said it's very simple and I guess it was. I successfully used it that way in Android strings.xml file. I was using it that way the whole day until suddenly android stopped to parse it and stopped to treat it like a variable.

I used it in this way:

```
<resources>
<string name="some_string">string1</string>
<string name="another_string"> {$some_string} trolololo </string>
</resources>
```

and in java accessing it through: getApplicationContext().getString(R.strings.another_string);

```
getApplicationContext().getString(R.strings.another_string);
```

In the output I used to receive string like:

```
string1 trolololo
```

and now I receive only:

```
{$some_string} trolololo
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong? I know that Android's XML may differ than standard XML, but IT USED TO WORK. Awww... Thanks for any advice.

Comment: try after cleaning your project, and `run` again.

Comment: Hm... I'm wondering, if this works also with other types like int or int[]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
<resources>
    <string name="some_string">string1</string>
    <string name="another_string">@string/some_string trolololo</string>
</resources>
```

Now the output of the `getApplicationContext().getString(R.strings.another_string)` will be `string1 trolololo`.

Comment: The interesting thing is when I try this, I get an error, `No resource found that matches at the given name (at 'another_string' with value '@string/some_string trolololo').`

Comment: [DevGuide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String) says that in XML resource references '@string/string_name'

Comment: Yes, it's the XML file that's throwing the error. I didn't manage to edit that into the comment in time before it locked.

Comment: @BogdanKobylinsky That is only useable in XML files other than the resource itself (such as views)

Comment: unfortunately this method with @string/some_string, doesn't. I saw the usage of strings in that way, but in the manifest file, but there it looks like that:
    <something value="@/string/some_string"> </something>

Answer (score 21):

Assuming that you want to pass a string value as a parameter in the `another_string` then your string is not well formatted to receive that argument and if you try to use it your output will be `{$some_string} trolololo`.

> If you need to format your strings using **String.format(String,
>   Object...)**, then you can do so by putting your format arguments in the
>   string resource.

```
<resources>
<string name="some_string">string1</string>
<string name="another_string">%1$s trolololo</string>
</resources>
```

Now your able to format the string with arguments from your application like this:

```
String arg = "It works!";
String testString = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.another_string), arg);
Log.i("ARG", "another_string = " + testString);
```

Doing so the output string will be `another_string = It works! trolololo`.

Take a look at the Android Developers official documentation, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already seen this method to format string(Earlier I was looking for solution on the Android Dev. documentation link you posted). And - Yes - That would solve my problem but I wanted to put all these strings into strings.xml file, prepare(concatenate) them there, and use these during runtime pre-prepared strings. The one thing I cannot understand is WHY it was working, and now it's not?

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can directly use `getResources().getString(R.string.activity_title, arg)`.

For example

```
<resources>
   <string name="postfix_title">%s Gallery</string>
</resources>
```

and then simply,

```
String arg = "Colors";
String title = getResources().getString(R.string.postfix_title, arg);
```

This will result in `title` containing value `Colors Gallery`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the first initial thing you've done was working with the curly brackets but i've run into this issue before and couldn't find a solution..

Now what I do is calling those strings separately and concatenate them during runtime.

Comment: using that curly brackets I could reference to some string value within this local document, and obviously that allowed me to concatenate them.